# Can CDT recursively add include paths from subdirectories

Tags: eclipse-cdt

Working on large scale projects where we get like 2k folders with sources in the project, providing all these folders manually as include paths for CDT is not really feasible.

Does CDT provide such a feature that adding the root folder of the project as an include path, it knows to search in all the sub-directories of the project?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There isn't an explicit feature for doing this, but I've found that checking `Allow heuristic resolution of includes` in `Preferences | C/C++ | Indexer` has the effect that the indexer will look for include files in all subdirectories of the project.

(This doesn't help you if you're adding the includes for the purposes of building in a Managed Build project. I would suggest using an external build system (make, CMake, ninja, etc.) in that case, as CDT Managed Build is mostly unmaintained these days anyways.)

Comment: We have an external build system that prepares that input, but to me it looks like an overhead to prepare such a list for a tool which should do it itself.
I'm also afraid the `heuristic resolution` will actually add more overhead and I'd stay away from things which are not well documented.